# C++: nested std::conditionals

Tags: c++, templates, conditional-statements, std

I have a simple image struct that contain among other things the actual image data. It can be stored in different orders. This is a simplification of the struct used:

```cpp
template <typename T, size_t C>
struct Image
{
public:


private:
    enum class ColorOrder1
    {
        UNKNOWN,
        INTENSITY
    };
    enum class ColorOrder3
    {
        UNKNOWN,
        RGB,
        BGR
    };

    enum class ColorOrder4
    {
        UNKNOWN,
        RGBA,
        BGRA
    };

public:
    using ColorOrder =
        typename std::conditional<C == 4, ColorOrder4,
                                  std::conditional<C == 3, ColorOrder3, ColorOrder1>>::type;

    // ColorOrder colorOrder;                      // <---- This works fine
    ColorOrder colorOrder = ColorOrder::UNKNOWN;   // <---- This does not

    std::shared_ptr<const std::vector<T>> data;

    /* .. and more data. but not imported */
};
```

I am trying to limit the possible color order based on the number of channels with the std::conditional. E.g. the order shouldn't be RGBA in case we only have a single channel image. This basically works. However, if I try to default the color order to `UNKNOWN` for all cases it doesn't compile anymore. Although `UNKNOWN` is present in all enums. The resulting error I get is:

```
 error: ‘UNKNOWN’ is not a member of ‘Image<unsigned char, 3>::ColorOrder’ {aka ‘std::conditional<true, Image<unsigned char, 3>::ColorOrder3, Image<unsigned char, 3>::ColorOrder1>’}
     ColorOrder colorOrder = ColorOrder::UNKNOWN;
```

I do assume that my nested `std::conditional` is actually failing. How to write this properly?

Thanks in advance for any feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You miss a `::type` for the inner `std::conditional`

```
using ColorOrder =
        typename std::conditional<C == 4,
                                  ColorOrder4,
                                  typename std::conditional<C == 3,
                                                            ColorOrder3,
                                                            ColorOrder1
                                                           >::type
                                  >::type;
```

Or in C++14,

```
using ColorOrder =
        std::conditional_t<C == 4,
                           ColorOrder4,
                           std::conditional_t<C == 3, ColorOrder3, ColorOrder1>>;
```

Comment: yes! thanks a lot!, I also just figured it out.

Comment: Oh yes, extra points for the C++14 version! Way nicer!

Answer (score 2):

I would do this in different way:

```cpp
public:
    using PossibleOrders = std::tuple<void, ColorOrder1, void, ColorOrder3, ColorOrder4>;
    using ColorOrder = typename std::tuple_element<C, PossibleOrders>::type;

    ColorOrder colorOrder = ColorOrder::UNKNOWN;
```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/TyBFNb)

IMO this approach is more flexible and much easier to read.

BTW use of `std::shared_ptr<const std::vector<T>>` is a bit strange. Probably you want to share data between images.

Comment: yes, this looks indeed quite nice.   What is strange with the shared_ptr?

Comment: As a side note: also here can `std::tuple_element_t` be used instead and furthermore `PossibleOrders` can be private.

Answer (score 1):

.. ah man, so quickly after asking the question I figured out what is wrong:

```cpp
    using ColorOrder = typename std::conditional<
        C == 4, ColorOrder4,
        typename std::conditional<C == 3, ColorOrder3, ColorOrder1>::type>::type;
```

Note the additional `typename` and `::type` which I missed before.

Comment: You can use `std::conditional_t` instead of `typename std::conditional` if you use C++14 or later. This is true for most type traits.